# how to get Inappbilling payments in my bank account

Tags: android

I am working in payment related apps and I am newbie for Google play, I added wallet account and enabled in app billing features successfully. So far I have been using test account for payments and I can able to see the list of purchases and financial related things in Merchant account (payment.google.com) but the problem is, where will be the real time purchase amount stored. How can I get to my own bank account.

I checked in wallet but not able to find my earnings.I don't know what I am doing wrong

Please guide me to know how and where to get the money of my inapppurchase items.

I would be great help also sharing reference site for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the revenue you make from in-app billing goes into your Google Play merchant account. If your revenue exceeds the minimum monthly threshold o f 1 USD, it will automatically be transferred into your bank account on a monthly basis. You can read more at https://support.google.com/payments/merchant/answer/3092796?hl=en

Comment: Thanks for the quick replay, So now I can able to see the time durations for payout etc in that link from TaJP shared. But tell me one thing that the payment was automatically credited on 15th of every month to our bank account which is added payment.google.com?

Comment: Yes that's correct. It will automatically be loaded into the Main card in your Google Wallet. If the answer helped you, please mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks.